# How to allocate more space inside a cell in a table?

Tags: tables, spacing, hyphenation, cell

I'd like to create an evenly distributed two columns table on a page. In order to have the vertical division centered, I used tabularx:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}
a & b \\
c & d \\
e & f \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

However, I have two problems:

1. for long words, I want it to look like this (made in MS Word - ignore the borders, they are there just to help visualize):

   [image: What I want]

   but in LaTeX I have:

   [image: What I have with Latex]

   I've tried a solution with `multirow`, unsuccessfully.
2. I keep getting the message *Overfull \hbox (86.11789pt too wide)*, but I don't understand why... maybe because the word is too long for its cell?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! For the ‘word’ in your screenshot, of course LaTeX does not know how to split it. ‘real words’ , it will know, in general. On your example, you can try `\seqsplit{aaaaa…}` (load the homonymous package) which splits a word anywhere.

Comment: Your solution really does the job. I didn't know the word should be 'real' to be splited by LaTeX. However, the writings will be in English, Portuguese and German. Would LaTeX still be able to split? Anyway, your solution will work. Thank you for your welcome and answer, Bernard!

Comment: You have to load the corresponding language files  through `babel` and select the active language at the moment, if necessary.

Comment: Oh! B.t.w., if you have problem with just a single word to split every now and  then, you may indicate the splitting points inserting a simple `\-` at these points.

Comment: Great! I was just thinking about that and \- is good enough. If you wish, please, answer the question in the proper section by copying and pasting what you've just said so I can accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it's really necessary; there are already many answers with this advice.

Comment: @Fran, I'm new to LaTeX and to TeX SX. I thought the problem was about having no enough space inside the cell to write the word, that's why it didn't occur to me looking for hyphenation before posting, although I had looked for allocating space topics. It seems you are a moderator - feel free to edit / close this thread as you find useful for the community. :)